# Android Studio - Error (bug) al entrar por segunda vez a un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigationview, navigation-drawer

**Descripción:**

Tengo un problema bastante particular que arrastro desde que cree **Navigation Drawer**. Tengo una actividad con nav drawer y nav view que uso para navegar en mi app. Uno de sus ítems nos lleva a un *Fragment Perfil* el cual tiene dentro un *View pager* con dos *fragments* (*Fragment perfil* y *Fragment dinero*):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(Fotos cortadas a la mitad por privacidad)**

El problema que tengo es que al entrar por segunda vez a mi fragment **Perfil**, las vistas desaparecen y el **view pager** empieza a funcionar mal. En la imágen se puede ver **Fragment Perfil** el cual muestra las vistas perfectamente al entrar por primera vez. Al entrar por segunda vez (haciendo click en *Perfil* en **Navigation view**) obtenemos el **Fragment perfil bugeado** el cual no solo no muestra las vistas de ninguno de los dos fragments dentro sino que también el view pager casi no se puede deslizar (es deslizable pero el desliz no es fluido (va trabado)).

Quiero resaltar que esto pasa siempre que ingreso al fragment por segunda vez. La primera vez nunca se traba.

**Que puede estar pasando? :(**

**Adjunto el código JAVA de la MainActivity que contiene el nav view y nav drawer:**

```
//SELECCIÓN DE LOS MENU ITEMS
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
            int menu_id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch(menu_id) {
                case R.id.nav_inicio:
                    fragment = new fragment_inicio();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_perfil:
                    fragment = new fragment_contenedor_perfil_alumno();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    break;
            }
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: El codigo que publicaste se ve bien, el problema debe estar en otro lugar.

Comment: Que crees que puede estar pasando? No sabría donde revisar

Comment: Podrias mostrar tambien el bloque de codigo de como esta implementado el viewPager.

Comment: No es un view pager. Es un navigation drawer / navigation view